# How to dynamically configure DataSource in Spring based on application mode?

Tags: spring, datasource

We have an application which runs both as standalone Spring application and as Webservice in Weblogic. The standalone application creates the database DataSource as show below by reading the properties file.

However for the Webservices part, I'd like to use the DataSource configured in Weblogic via JNDI. I'm not sure how to make that dynamic DataSource switch based on the mode my application runs. Any help here please?

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources(value = {@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")})
public class DAOConfig {
    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new DataSources.Builder()
                .host(env.getProperty("dbhost"))
                .port(env.getProperty("dbport", Integer.class))
                .service(env.getProperty("dbservice"))
                .user(env.getProperty("dbuser"))
                .pwd(env.getProperty("dbpwd"))
                .initialConnectionsInPool(env.getProperty("dbinitialConnectionsInPool", Integer.class))
                .maxConnectionsInPool(env.getProperty("dbmaxConnectionsInPool", Integer.class))
                .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [spring profiles](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/), example below using xml config :

```
    <beans profile="production">
        <bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
            <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig"/>
        </bean>
    </beans>

    <beans profile="development">
        <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2">
            <jdbc:script location="classpath:/sql/createSchema.sql"/>
        </jdbc:embedded-database>
    </beans>
```

Then add as parameter when starting application :

```
-Dspring.profiles.active="development""
```